# What if I realize that I should have split a question in two separate questions?

Tags: support, questions, multiple-questions

#### Context

Some days ago I made a question on a SE website, and since I thought that two issues were such related and interdependent that they were semantically equivalent to just one question, I decided to ask about **both of them in the same question**.

But afterwards I realized that what I did was *wrong* because a solution to just one of the two issues would have been extremely useful independently of whether the answerer has a solution for the other issue or not.

Plus, since the two issues are quite **difficult** to solve, even solving just one of them would be extremely helpful and appreciated.

And I thought that this may prevent answerers who have a solution to just one of the to issues from answering, or they may put that solution just as a comment, because they may think it would be not enough for an answer. And even in this case I think that putting a good solution as a comment just because it answers to only one of two questions would not be good for the readability of a Q&A website.

#### So my question is:

What do you suggest me to do if I realize afterwards that a question should have been split in two separate questions?

The alternatives I have in mind are below.

1. **Leaving the question as it is**, perhaps the usual behaviour of the answerers may be to put an answer even if it only solves one of the two issues? And how would **acceptance** work in this case?
2. **Editing the question to ask only one thing and making a new question to ask the other thing.** This seems nice, but there are two comments under the question in which one user reasons about both issues. Should I leave them there? Maybe I could add his suggestion to the second question I create afterwards?
3. **Deleting the question and making two new questions.** This seems also reasonable, but again what should I do with the two comments mentioned above?

If you have other ideas in mind apart from the three above they are very welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

4. **Delete the question and edit it to ask only one question, create a separate question for the other issue. When you're finished with editing the first question, undelete it.**

You can undelete your own posts, if you deleted them.

This way, you prevent users from posting answers before the issue is resolved.

Regarding the comments - you could use the info to already improve the second question. You could also notify the commenter (@username) of what you did.

If you're too late and already received an answer, you may flag your post and ask a mod to close it while you finish editing it. Then sort out the issue, also by explaining the situation in a comment to the answer. The answerer may then split their answer into two answers - one to each question.

Regarding your question

> And how would **acceptance** work in this case?

Not very well, unless the answer answered both questions sufficiently. That's why questions on SE should only contain one question.

Comment: Many thanks @Anne , this is very good advice. As for "That's why questions on SE should only contain one question", it's just because initially I thought the two issues were very relate and interdependent, so much that they were _semantically_ making just one question. But, as I said, I was wrong and I realized they were much more independent than I thought initially.